# Twillio SMS support in The Netherlands

Tags: azure

I want to test an Azure Logic app that uses a service like Twillio to send SMS messages. Unfortunately Twillio doesn't offer SMS support in The Netherlands. What alternatives could we choose to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used **messagebird.com** for this and build their API into a custom API App that I embedded in a Logic App flow:

```
Client client = Client.CreateDefault("[API KEY]" , null); 
Message messageResponse = client.SendMessage(message.Sender,
    message.MessageText, new[] { long.Parse(message.Number) });
```

This could also be implemented in an Azure Function to simplify deployment.